# How to convert response of AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using AVAssetExportSession for Audio Recording with assert and here is my code to convert AVAssert to AVAssertExportSession.

```
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:self.asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL URLWithString:dataPath];
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    NSLog(@".... Audio... %@",exportSession);
}];
```

It gives me output like this

```
<AVAssetExportSession: 0x177f4b30, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x18981f60, URL = file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8BB39AD5-EEFB-4AF1-A913-B26C5C072E61/tmp/1422861622SCVideo.0.m4a>, presetName = AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A, outputFileType = com.apple.m4a-audio
```

Here i just want URL to NSString.

Help me for this

Comment: What is **URL to NSString**.

Comment: I want only this part "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8BB39AD5-EEFB-4AF1-A913-B26C5C072E61/tmp/1422861622SCVideo.0.m4a" As a string

Comment: Isn't `dataPath` or `outputURL ` what you are looking for?

Comment: dataPath doesn't working and outputURL gives only "file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8BB39AD5-EEFB-4AF1-A913-B26C5C072E61/tmp/" but i want filename in postfix of url.

Comment: Please refer to my answer to see if it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the export session is complete, you can get what you want. Because it is an asynchronous operation.

```
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"failed");
        } else if(exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted){
            NSLog(@"completed!");
            // here you can get the output url.
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Yes it works now i know where i am getting wrong. Thanks...:)

Comment: So where exactly was the problem?

Comment: It Goes on failed Status. So for the reason It not give me proper url. Nyway thanks for help.